# d3 changing loaded ajax data

Tags: ajax, d3.js

I have the data loaded from ajax:

```
 if (page == 1) {
        var n = date.toISOString();
        $.ajax({  
            url: route,
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ "year": n }),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {
                var data = JSON.parse(result);
                console.log(data);
                draw(data);
            }

        });
```

I want the draw(data) function to draw a barchart depending on the year choosen from the range slider. But the thing is, i also need a condition:

```
  var date;
var val = document.getElementById("year");
    switch (val) {
        case '2015': date = new Date("July 21, 2015"); break;
        case '2016': date = new Date("July 21, 2016"); break;
        case "2017": date = new Date("July 21, 2017"); break;
        case '2019': date = new Date("July 21, 2019"); break;
        default: date = new Date("July 21, 2018"); break;
    }
```

Depending on chosen date it should post a different date. Here's an html range code:

```
<input type="range" min=2015 max=2019 step=1 id="year" value=2018 oninput="selected_year.value = year.value">
        <output name="selected_year" id="selected_year">2018</output>
```

It only loads the "default" value which is 2018. 
Well, how to make my barchart change the loaded data depending on the year chosen from range? What am i exactly doing wrong?

Comment: You compare the DOM element (<input>) with a year not its value.  Change to switch(val.value) {

Comment: @ee2Dev, thanks, i did, but still no result.

Comment: It seems you compare value (a number) with strings. Try to remove the brackets in the case statements: case 2015: ...

Comment: Quotation marks I mean - not brackets